# How to rewrite SQL xpath query to be able to create an indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, xpath, view, indexing

I have a view that extracts some info from a table with xml data.
Each document contains one `Product` and several `PurchaseOrderDetail`. I want to create a view with all `PurchaseOrderDetail` for each `Product`.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[XML_PurchaseOrders]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT
    p.n.value('.', 'int') AS PurchaseOrderID
    ,x.ProductID
    FROM dbo.XmlLoadData x
    CROSS APPLY x.PayLoad.nodes('declare namespace NS="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XmlDbPerfTest"; 
    /NS:ProductAndRelated/NS:Product/NS:PurchaseOrderDetails/NS:PurchaseOrderDetail/NS:PurchaseOrderID') p(n)
GO
```

The `PayLoad` column contains the XML data.

The problem with this view is that it is painfully slow since the XML documents are both large and plentiful.

I would like to index this view but that gives me the error

> Cannot create index on view "XmlLoad.dbo.XML_PurchaseOrders" because it contains an APPLY. Consider not indexing the view, or removing APPLY.

**Is it possible to rewrite the view to make it possible to add an index?**

I have tried several attempts, mostly with `select ... from (select ....) innnerSelect group by foo` but the all fall down on one or another rule regarding indexes on views.

Comment: Since you need to use multiple nodes from your XML, I don't see how you can do it without `CROSS APPLY` and thus I don't see how you could do it in such a view that you could create an indexed view over it :-(

Comment: @marc_s, me neither, but I hoped there was some other way to expand the XML that I did not know about.

Comment: I assume there isn't an option to extract this data out of the XML and store in relational tables?

Comment: @billinkc, that is what I'm currently doing. But it would be nicer to have an indexed view to avoid maintaining the other tables and make sure the relational tables does not come out of sync with the main tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Is it possible to rewrite the view to make it possible to add an index?
```

No. I don't think so. Instead I'm going to use some info from [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8445/performance-issue-with-xpath-in-sql-server-2008) question and suggest another way.

You can add a calculated persisted column to your table that only holds the XML that has the id's. It is not allowed to use XQUERY stuff directly in a computed column but you can do it with a user defined function.

Here is the function:

```
create function dbo.GetPurchaseOrderID(@XMLData xml) 
returns xml with schemabinding
as
begin
  return @XMLData.query('declare namespace NS="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XmlDbPerfTest"; 
    /NS:ProductAndRelated/NS:Product/NS:PurchaseOrderDetails/NS:PurchaseOrderDetail/NS:PurchaseOrderID')
end
```

Create the table with the persisted XML column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XmlLoadData](
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL identity,
    [PayLoad] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [Size]  AS (len(CONVERT([nvarchar](max),[PayLoad],0))),
    [PurchaseOrderIDs] AS dbo.GetPurchaseOrderID(PayLoad) PERSISTED,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_XmlLoadData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
       IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
       ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Query to get the IDs:

```
;with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XmlDbPerfTest' as NS)
select ProductID,
       P.N.value('.', 'int') as PurchaseOrderID
from XmlLoadData
  cross apply PurchaseOrderIDs.nodes('NS:PurchaseOrderID') as P(N)
```

Limited testing on my part shows that it is a bit faster. If your XML documents are large it ought to be a bigger improvement. I doubt it will improve performance by 1000x because you are still dealing with interpreting XML but you tell me. I have of course no way of testing that without your data.

Comment: That sounds very interesting. I think I can use a function to build a stripped down version of the XML with just the data I need for the view (in real life I have more data than one item). Then I can create my view from that minimal XML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an XML index?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934097.aspx

Comment: An XML index is not an option. It adds at least 10GB to the database size and we frequently juggle database copies over the network. I only want to index a small fraction of the content in the XML data. The xml documents are large and many.

Comment: I also tried an XML index on a smaller subset of the data, but the improvements was only about 2x. I need 1000x or so.